# Need to download array of objects as a pdf report in React Js which having hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

```
let data = [{
  profile1: <a href="facebook.com">facebook</a>,
  name: 'Name',
  profile2: <a href="google.com">google</a>,
  age: 23,
  country: 'ABc'
}]
```

Need to view above data as pdf report with hyperlinks as well. I tried using jspdf, jsautotable and react-pdf packages as well but no luck.

Comment: Hi Lokesh and welcome to SO. Please be sure to be detailed in your question. What do you mean with "view above data as PDF report"? What does that look like? Please also include your attempts.

Comment: Aha, for now, I understand why it doesn't work for you)))
Look at your href's.

Comment: const downloadPdf = () => {const input = tableRef.current;
    html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
      pdf.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 10, 10, 190, 0);
      const links = input.querySelectorAll("a");
      links.forEach((link) => {const rect = link.getBoundingClientRect();
        const linkText = link.getAttribute("href") || "";
        pdf.textWithLink("Clickhere", rect.left + 10, rect.top + 10, {
          url: linkText});
      });
      pdf.save("report.pdf");
    });
  };

Comment: Need to render above data as table and to download it as pdf format

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Go and read the documentation how it woks.

For installation:
`npm install pdfmake` or for TypeScript `npm i --save-dev @types/pdfmake`

```
import React from "react";
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";

pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

const generatePDF = () => {
  const documentDefinition = {
    content: [
      { text: "Profile 1: facebook", link: "https://www.facebook.com" },
      { text: "Name: Name" },
      { text: "Profile 2: google", link: "https://www.google.com" },
      { text: "Age: 23" },
      { text: "Country: ABC" },
    ],
  };

  const pdfDoc = pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition);
  pdfDoc.download("report.pdf");
};

const PdfReport: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={generatePDF}>Generate PDF</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PdfReport;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but need to capture clickable hyperlinks in a PDF generated from an HTML table.